# Could not find com.mapbox.gradle.plugins:sdk-registry:0.3.0

Tags: android, sdk

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'abc'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.mapbox.gradle.plugins:sdk-registry:0.3.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> - https://maven.google.com/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> - https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.3.0/sdk-registry-0.3.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like mapbox problem. Here is a thread:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/issues/1285

If u want to make it work temporary u can use jcenter() as one of user suggested in linked thread, but remember jcenter() is not supported anymore.